# Selenium Webdriver C# Unable to locate element in Chrome with valid XPath expression

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing Selenium scripts with C# for a web app, I've made a lot of scripts successfully but have just come across a button which I cannot get Selenium to click. Strangely, there seems nothing different about this button to other buttons I've had Selenium click. The HTML for the button is:

```
<button class="contact-us-button btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="showCancelModal()" type="button">Cancel</button>
```

As there aren't any unique Ids or ClassNames for this button and there are multiple buttons on this form, I'm trying to select by Xpath using this code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//*[@id='mainView']/div/form/div/div/div[4]/button[1]")).Click();
```

I got the XPath from Google Chrome by inspecting the button and copying the Xpath from the button element. I've also tried replacing `*` with `div` which hasn't worked. The XPath doesn't seem incorrect, yet I keep getting the following exception

> OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : invalid selector: Unable to
>   locate an element with the xpath expression
>   (//div[@id='mainView']/div/form/div/div/div[4]/button[1]

Could anyone help, as I don't know why using this XPath to select the element isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is typo in your xpath

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//*[@id='mainView']/div/form/div/div/div[4]/button[1]")).Click();
```

change as below and let me know

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mainView']/div/form/div/div/div[4]/button[1]")).Click();
```

Comment: You're right it was a typo. I goofed. The actual code is: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mainView']/div/form/div/div/div[4]/button[1]")).Click();

Comment: If you edit your code to has the closing bracket I'll tick you as correct answer for pointing me in the right direction :) thanks alot!

Comment: @smithsnm, Sorry this was my typo :) , update the same.